# ASP.NET MVC web api with multiple HttpPosts methods not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have these two post methods in my ASP.NET API Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("post1")]
    public bool PostGradingTasks(List<Reports> landingCells)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("post2")]
    public String UploadImages(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    }
```

But when I call PostGradingTasks from this app I am building, it does not get called, only when I completely remove UploadImages it works: here are my routes

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApiWithAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{bool}",
                defaults: new { communityRedBlue = RouteParameter.Optional, isAlphabeticalSort = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ControllerAndAction",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
        }
    }
```

I just added this route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                    name: "ControllerAndAction",
                    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
                );
```

But its still not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nope didnt work

Comment: No idea....I cant run the project locally, only on a server.

Comment: I've actually decided to combine both Post methods, turns out I dont need two anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use attribute routing which IMO is a better design then convention routes. Set it up by using Route/RoutePrefix attributes on the controller and methods.

Here's an example for your post methods

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestController: ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("post1")] //api/test/post1
    public bool PostGradingTasks(List<Reports> landingCells)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("post2")] //api/test/post2
    public String UploadImages(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    }
}
```